# Airflow: How to trigger a dag multiple times and queuing the DagRuns for running one at a time

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, kubernetespodoperator

I have a job that i want airflow to do, but this job cannot run in parralel.
This job is based on a docker image that airflow will trigger using KubernetesPodOperator with the specific command.
I want to create a DAG that will do this job once at a time, but this DAG can be trigger multiples time while an instance of DagRuns is running.
So my question is : There is a way to trigger a DAG, so that each DagRuns is queued somewhere and the DAG is listening to that queue and run when fetching from that queue.
So that no Trigger will be ommited.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Airflow pools can be used to limit the execution parallelism on arbitrary sets of tasks. The list of pools is managed in the UI (Menu -> Admin -> Pools) by giving the pools a name and assigning it a number of worker slots.

for more details see this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/pools.html)

Comment: thanks but task == operator, i want way of queuing httpTrigger of a specific dag. Lets say i have a dag doing a spark job called myDag and i have an platform(ui) from which you can trigger myDag.I don't want that dag to run in parralell if 2 people or more click on the trigger at the same time, i want the run to be sequential doint all the trigger in the order

Comment: set max_active_runs=1 in the dag